# Mongoose .findOne returns document first, and then NULL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When going to the user route, first it returns the document. Again(I don't restart), it returns null. Here's the code:

```
       app.get("/author/:name", function(req,res,next) {
         Article.find({ author : req.params.name},function(err,allArticle) {  // find all documents associated with the name
            if(err) {
              console.log(err);
              next();  
            } else {
              res.locals.article = allArticle;
              next();              
            }
        })
     }, function(req,res) {
         User.findOne({username : req.params.name}, function(err,user) {
           if(err) {       // find user with the name in the route
              console.log(err);
            } else {
            console.log(user);
            res.locals.user = user;
            res.locals.user.bio = marked( user.bio );
            res.render("showAuthor", res.locals);
     }
    })
  })
```

[image: Output]

That means "user" is null, when it just returned it to us earlier. Also, I tried it with "article", and the same output.

Not sure why this weird behavior is happening, ONLY ON THIS ROUTE!

It'd be great if anyone can help me with this.

Thanks!

Comment: If you stick in a `console.log(res.locals)` after the `console.log(user)` statement, what's logged?

Comment: @chridam `console.log(user)` returns undefined, and `console.log(res.locals)` returns null

Comment: @chridam And if I use `.find()`, both output correct the first time, then user is undefined. So no problem with `res.locals.user`. If I `console.log(allArticle[0])`, the same thing happens.

Comment: Try adding `next` parameter for the second function in the middleware sub-stack i.e. `app.get("/author/:name", middleware1Callback, function(req,res,next) {  User.findOne(...) })`

Comment: @chridam I'm sorry, I didn't quite get it. What should `middleware1Callback` be?

Comment: `middleware1Callback` is just a variable representation of the first middleware function `function(req,res,next) { Article.find(...) }`.

Comment: @chridam I tried the route in  [the simplest way](https://imgur.com/ypEDl7F). This isn't working as well (on this route)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164551/discussion-between-chridam-and-eknoor4197).

Comment: Could you please show your view, maybe the url is changed when you hit `/author/:name`

Comment: @YouneL I can send as many requests with Postman, and the output in the console is correct. But as soon as the page is loaded, it's undefined

Comment: That's why I told you to show your view

Comment: @YouneL "view" as in my page template (ejs file)? Sorry, I'm a noob!

Comment: @eknoor4197, Yes it's

Comment: This is the [code](https://imgur.com/yn0UTJG.jpg)

Comment: Try to add: `<span><%= '/author/' + article.author %></span>` just before `<span><em>By <a class="author" href="/author/<%= article.author %>">...` to see what is generated as url

Comment: @YouneL Tried, didn't work :(

Comment: This is not suppose to resolve the problem, it's for debugging purpose, just a way to understand where the problem come from. when you add span tag what result do you get, can you show it please

Comment: @YouneL `/author/Eknoorpreet Singh` This is the same as `req.params.name` aka The problematic route

Comment: it always shows you the same value `/author/Eknoorpreet Singh`

Comment: @YouneL Tried with another user.At first, it's fine. But as soon as I inserted some articles and made him the author, he's undefined!

Comment: @chridam Hey, I tried [something](https://imgur.com/mDNjmGN.jpg) here to make the issue a bit clearer. Here's the [result](https://imgur.com/hcihAFh.jpg)